# How to make Company optional for a Lead?

Tags: leads

Like many folk out there, I want to remove the requirement that a new Lead object needs to have something in the Company field. From various discussions ([like this one](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Nonprofits/COMPANY-field-required-in-Lead/td-p/45115)) it looks like it is not possible to make it a non-required field.

BUT, I have worked on an instance where the following piece of test code runs perfectly fine:

```
Lead freshLead = new Lead();
freshLead.Email = 'nomatch@example.com';
freshLead.LeadSource = 'Email';
freshLead.FirstName = 'John';
freshLead.LastName = 'Doe';
// note: no freshLead.Company = 'Unknown';
insert freshLead;
```

How is this done?

Comment: Odd, using execute anonymous on V29: `insert new Lead(lastName='foo', email='foo@bar.com');` I get "DMLException Required Fields are Missing: Company". Unlimited Edition org. I would agree with Greenstork that a beforeInsert trigger must be defaulting the company field if null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the field not required by requesting [Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_person.htm&language=en_US) be enabled in your organization. Failing that, there would necessarily be a before insert trigger in play. It may be in a managed package installed, in which case you may not be able to determine the origin of the update.

Comment: ah, but of course.  A lead w/o a company won't convert to an Account (name is required field) unless Person Accounts are enabled

Comment: That's it. The org in question has Person Accounts enabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would need a before insert trigger on Lead that populates the Company field if it is null.

Comment: That is a bright idea that I didn't think of. But, there is definitely no before insert trigger on the Lead in that org. The above code snippet is on Lead (after insert)